Using a dictionary for hyphenation instead of hyphenation patterns?
As we just discussed in another question from today, the hyphenation pattern system used by TeX can sometimes yield unsatisfactory results. As far as I understand, most other document preparation software uses dictionaries rather than Knuth’s hyphenation pattern system. I wonder if it is possible (and feasible) to turn off the hyphenation pattern system completely and just load some dictionary into TeX?
I assume that the answer is probably yes, in theory at least. After all, I could make my own format and remove all hyphenation patterns and just load an entire dictionary using \hyphenation{...}. But is there a more straightforward and practical way to do this? And will it negatively affect performance too much?

as the other question shows the patterns work fine, it only can happen that one need to extend them if a setting is missing. What would you gain by a dictionary? It would never be complete and perfect either.

The accuracy of hyphenation is not primarily determined by the algorithm used (whether pattern-based or dictionary-based), but rather by the quality of the data provided. AFAIK, InDesign relies on Hunspell, but we cannot assume this program is perfect. As your previous question shows, the pattern-based algorithm has its advantages. In fact, a dictionary-based one would force you to modify all problematic words, which is what you wanted to avoid.

actually the Liang hyphenation algorithm and the tex patterns that go with it is used by several non tex systems, open office, hyphenation.js in web browsers, ...  these days you probably have the memory to simply load thousands of words into \hyphenation{....} but why? the patterns compress that data considerably and extend to words you don't list and you can always add \hyphenation to correct any bad cases.

see https://www.tug.org/docs/liang/liang-thesis.pdf

I don't see how "call \hyphenation{...} for every word in a dictionary" could possibly be better than "call \hyphenation{...} for the exceptions that aren't covered by the algorithm".  My wild guess is that your other question uncovered a bug in the Danish hyphenation patterns that will be fixed in the near future.

Anyway, I think it shouldn’t be difficult to write a tool in Lua comparing a list of hyphenated words against the results of TeX. Then, a list of exceptions can be built, which, I think, shouldn’t be too large. I have something like that for Spanish, although not exactly, because Spanish hyphenation is based on rules, not in morphological analysis, so it cannot be directly adapted.

A dictionary for hyphenation should contain all inflected forms; not a big deal for English, but think to Polish or, worse, Finnish, that’s nor only inflected, but agglutinating.

I think the basic assumption here is flawed. Given a suitably large hyphenation dictionary (and for many languages these are not generally available but proprietary data held by dictionary publishers) You can generate \patterns that greatly compress that data and produce an acceptable percentage of the listed hyphenation points and insert no unwanted points. The patterns will have the big advantage over the original dictionary list that as well as being a lot smaller they will naturally apply to any similarly constructed words that were not in the list.
The TeXBook says of the hyphens that are still used in the default US English plain TeX and LaTeX configurations:

Plain TeX loads exactly 4447 patterns into TeX's memory, beginning with
.ach4 and ending with 4z1z2 and
z4zy. The interletter values in these patterns are all
between 0 and 5; a large odd value like the 5 in h5elo
forces desirable hyphen points in words like bach-e-lor and
ech-e-lon, while a large even value like the 4 in hach4
suppresses undesirable hyphens in words like tooth-ache. Liang
derived these patterns by preparing a special version of Webster's
Pocket Dictionary (Merriam, 1966) that contains about 50,000 words including
derived forms. Then he checked a preliminary set of patterns obtained from
this data against an up-to-date hyphenation dictionary of about
115,000 words obtained from a publisher; errors found in this run
led to the addition of about 1000 words like camp-fire,
Af-ghan-i-stan, and bio-rhythm to the pocket dictionary list. He
weighted a few thousand common words more heavily so that they would be more
likely to be hyphenated; as a result, the patterns of plain TeX guarantee
complete hyphenation of the 700 or so most common words of English,
as well as common technical words like al-go-rithm. These patterns
find 89.3% of the hyphens in Liang's dictionary as a whole, and
they insert no hyphens that are not present.

The algorithm is described in Liang's thesis https://www.tug.org/docs/liang/liang-thesis.pdf
That said, the memory taken up by putting an entire hyphenation dictionary into \hyphenation is probably not too large by modern standards, You probably have several orders of magnitude more memory available than when these patterns were made in the early 1980's.
You can simply try it if you have the data.

How could camp-fire possibly be hyphenated anywhere else? Is mpf supposed to be part of a hyphenation pattern in English? In German, schur enoff, but not in English. I hope Mein Kampf is not popular enough in the U.K. to justify its own hyphenation pattern.

@Gaussler most likely it did not find the hyphenation at all.  your question about mpf doesn't really correspond with how patgen works. You do not consider individual sylables you give patgen an entire dictionary of complete words and it extracts whatever strings it needs to compress it, you can't look at the list of patterns and ask why that pattern was chosen, they are not individualy chosen, they are all generated together as part of a compression algorithm

I hope that most of patterns used by TeX (an by other applications mentioned in the discussion) are generated by the patgen program (created by Liang). Its input was a dictionary with hyphenation points specified and the output is the TeX pattern. If TeX uses this pattern then it is almost the same as the usage of original dictionary but with a great difference: data amount is extremely reduced. This is main reason of existence the patgen program and patterns usage instead whole dictionaries.
Another important aspect of existence of patterns is computational speed. The dictionaries must be read an processed by patgen in many steps and this takes significant time because the huge amount of data is processed. In the early days of TeX, patgen processing took several hours. On other hand, reading and using patgen output (patterns) by TeX takes a few second (today mini-second).
Maybe, there are heuristically created patterns for some languages because the dictionary for such languages was not free available. If you have your private dictionary for your language then you can use patgen to generate patterns and then use your private patterns in TeX.

Let’s assume there is a list with lots of words with the ‘correct’ hyphenation points. I’ve created a very short list, but you should be aware a typical list may contains hundreds of thousands of words (my list for Spanish contains about 750 000). Here is the list, which is stored in wordlist.txt:
dy-na-mics
me-cha-nics
be-greb
li-ne-æ-re
tids-for-stå-el-se
of-test
bru-ges
hæn-del-sers
kon-stan-te
be-væ-gel-se
for-tid
må-les
må-ne-der
se-kun-der
in-ter-val-let

If you run the tex file below with luatex, it will show the words in the list not matching the hyphenation done by the patterns. With the list above, it will show in the log:
=========
dy-na-mics
me-cha-nics
=========)

Then, you can use the result to build your own exception list. Here is the tex file:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[danish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\newread\instream

\openin\instream=wordlist.txt

\directlua{ texio.write_nl('=========') }

\loop
\ifeof\instream\else
  \endlinechar-1  
  \read\instream to \word
  \endlinechar`\^^M
  \directlua{
    word = string.gsub("\word", ' ', '' )
    base = word:gsub('-', '' )
  }
  \setbox0\hbox{\directlua{ tex.print( base ) }}
  \directlua{
    result = ''
    for item in node.traverse(tex.box[0].head) do
      if item.id == 29 then
        result = result .. unicode.utf8.char(item.char)
      elseif item.id == 7 then
        result = result .. '-'
      end
    end
    if not (result == word) then
      texio.write_nl(word)
    end
  }
\repeat
\directlua{ texio.write_nl('=========') }

\stop

Note. I don’t know if there is already something like this in CTAN. If not, and since I think it can be useful, feel free to improve it and create a package.

If I used algorithms to generate the most random list of Danish words possible, it couldn't have done a better job.
